# Correct way to handle user permissions with Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm quite new to Cloud Storage solutions, and I'm currently researching options to upgrade our current solution (we currently just upload on a SVN server).

What I have is a native application running on client computers, which will upload data to the Cloud Storage.  Afterwards, client should be able to download and browse their data (source is not set in stone, could be a website or from other applications).  They should not be able to access other user's data.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to proceed.  As far as I understand, the native application will upload using a Native Application Credential, using JSON.

Do I need multiple credentials to track multiple users?  That seems wrong to me.  Besides when they come back as 'users' through the web interface, they wouldn't be using that authentification, would they?

Do I need to change the ACL of the uploaded files afterwards?

Should I just not give write/read access to any particular users and handle read requests through Signed URLs, dealing with permission details by myself using something else on the side?  (not forcing a Google Account is probably a requirement)

Sorry if this is too many questions, and thanks!

Benjamin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you've got a lot of questions about a theoretical problem you haven't yet tried to tackle. Unfortunately I can't see a way that your question can be answered right now, it's not very clear what _specific_ problem you're trying to solve (it looks more like you're trying to start a discussion) and there's no indication of what language you're using in the question tags. I'd advise making some attempt at solving the problems yourself and if you come across specific programming/implementation problems, then ask about those issues as individual questions.

Comment: You're probably right.  I guess I shouldn't (and wouldn't) be here if it wasn't for the fact that the only line of support for Google Cloud (while in evaluation) is StackOverflow.

It's a problem I can solve in many ways, I was just hoping for an answer from Google to know what they consider the 'correct' way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "individual credentials per instance of an app" question has come up before, and unfortunately there's not a great answer. If you want every user to have different permissions, you need every user to be associated with a different account.

Like you point out, the best current answer, other than requiring users to have Google accounts, is to have a centralized service that vends signed URLs to the end applications. That service would be the only owner of all of the objects and would give out permission to read or upload as needed.